# how to write if statement in accordance to the "name" in a cell and the amount of characters

Tags: google-apps-script

Using google docs script:

I want to write a code that will check all of row B(lets say B2), using a loop, and if it says "dogs" i want the correcponding cells(lets say D2) to have 8 characters("00000000") and have multiple of these with different words will check if the corresponding column has a certain number of characters.

I also want it to show an error if there is more or less than the allowed charaters in the correcsponding column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function countChar(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

  var range = sheet.getRange("B4");
  var char = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(char)
  Logger.log("length: "+ char.length);

}
```

According to this document:

> [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) is a scripting language based on JavaScript that lets you do new and cool things with G Suite products like Docs, Sheets, and Forms.

Since GAS is based from Javascript you can use [JavaScript String length Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_string.asp) to get the length of a variable.

Hope this helps.